# Windows Phone 8: How to bind Data?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, integer

I have a question about WP8 coding. I have a TextBox for numbers. I want calculate with the number (who has been typed in the box) on another Page. This means, that I don t want to show the number on the next Page, I want to get access to the typed value.

So what is the best way to do this?

Thanks to all answers!

Answer (score 0):

Your question not seemed very clear to me. But if you are asking how to pass data between pages, you can do:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/destinationPage.xaml?dataName=",value));
```

In the destination page you can access the data this way:

```
string targetValue;
If(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("dataName", out targetValue))
{
    //targetValue will contain value, you can do anything with it
}
```

---

DataBinding to controls is different thing:

```
<TextBox Binding={tBoxValue, Mode = TwoWay} x:name="tbox"/>
```

Now in code consider `presenter` is an object, which contains a property `tBoxValue`:
If you do:

```
tBox.DataContext = presenter;
```

You can access the data entered in the `TextBox` via `presenter.tBoxValue`;

Comment: what actually is "dataName"? is it the binding in the textbox?
and is it a difference, when i want to use an integer value instead a string value?

Comment: new Uri("/destinationPage.xaml?dataName=",value); // dataName is this dataName ( key for your value). int.Parse() return a int from equivalent string 
( destination page). int.ToString() returns a string representation of int ( you dont need this one, just told howto do this).